# php file not found error on goDaddy hosting

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting, file-not-found

So I have uploaded a php file on my goDaddy hosting the file is in the public_html folder

but whenever I am trying to access that file I am keep getting file not found error.

that file was easily accessible on my previous host.

Here is the file location:
[image: here is the file location]

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Comment: http://43.255.154.97/home.html also not found check the file permission.and also check the 404.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to access the file when using the ip but when using the domain name it worked fine.

Try changing it from ip/script.php to your-domain-name/script.php